# C# Call static method which defers to child static method

Tags: c#

I have a model (`Structure`) and another which inherits from this (`Structure : StaticStructure`)

I also have a controller which calls the static method on `Structure`:

```
// Controller
 Structure obj = Structure.PlaceInstance(StructurePrototypes[objectType])

// Structure model    
public static Structure PlaceInstance ( Structure prototype )
```

What I would like is to call the `PlaceInstance` of `StaticStructure` instead. The problem I am facing is with the Types. As you can see, I am getting a prototype from a Dictionary and then calling `Structure.PlaceInstance`. But they won't ever be typeof Structure, they could be `StructureStatic` or something else.

I basically want a parent class `Structure` which other classes will inherit from `StructureStatic`. The parent structure class will hold generic methods available to every structure and then the child classes will hold specific methods pertaining to them.

I know I can't override static methods and I know this method can't be abstract without the whole `Structure` class being abstract.

One thought would be to maybe pass the controller the class name and then do something like (pseudo code):

```
[className] obj = [className].PlaceInstance()
```

EDIT:

Let me try to clarify the issue. I used to have one big model `Structure` but not all structures use all those methods, so in an attempt to avoid alot of bools and if statements, I wanted to split them.

`StructurePrototypes` is a dictionary that is populated from an XML file (not important).

```
// the string is the ID
StructurePrototypes = new Dictionary<string, Structure>();
```

When placing a structure, the current code is used:

```
Structure obj = Structure.PlaceInstance( StructurePrototypes[objectType]
```

As you can see, this assumes `Structure` but the items in the dictionary will never be `Structure`, they will all be models that inherit Structure.

So I need some way to call the `PlaceInstance` method on the actual model and probably remove the `PlaceInstance` method on `Structure` alltogether.

Comment: Static members are not inherited, so there’s no way to tell the compiler to call a static method on a type without actually using that exact type. So you could not even have a generic method `PlaceInstance<T>` which then called the `PlaceInstance` on the type `T`. That simply does not work (unless you use reflection). – [What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542) Show a bit more of your use case instead of focusing on trying to solve it with a solution that will not work.

Comment: Thanks @poke, I edited the question.

Comment: Just make `PlaceInstance` non-static, then do `StructurePrototypes[objectType].PlaceInstance()`.

Comment: I could do that @Evk but the dictionary still references `Structure` as a type. I don't really want a Dictionary for each Structure type `StructureStatic` for example.

Comment: In all your examples, `StructurePrototypes[objectType]` returns instance of structure, not type.